# The data I get from Firebase does not enter the if else control

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

```
  val energy = enerjiText.text.toString()

    if (energy < 50 .toString()){
        progressBar.max = 1000
        val currentProgress = 900

        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar,"progress",currentProgress)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .start()

        progressBar2.max = 1000
        val currentProgress2 = 700

        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar2,"progress",currentProgress2)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .start()
    }
    else{
        progressBar.max = 1000
        val currentProgress = 600

        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar,"progress",currentProgress)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .start()

        progressBar2.max = 1000
        val currentProgress2 = 300

        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar2,"progress",currentProgress2)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .start()
    }
```

The id of the textView circled in black is enerjiText. In this textView I am printing the data that I have saved in firestore. But without checking the values ​​in the if-else loop you see in the code, the progress bars inside the if push the screen. I gave the value of energy < 50 in the if, the answer is 227, but it shows the progress bar values ​​in the if without going into the else loop. If I don't convert the enerjiText and the energy < 50 control to string I get the error "java lang numberformatexception For input string"

```
val panelC = binding.panelCount3.text.toString()
        val landSl = binding.landSlope.text.toString()
        val landS = binding.landSize3.text.toString()
        val billT = binding.bill.text.toString()

        if (panelC.isEmpty() || landSl.isEmpty() || landS.isEmpty() || billT.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Alanları Doldurun",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else{
            val pco = panelC.toInt()
            val lsl = landSl.toInt()
            val ls = landS.toInt()
            val b = billT.toInt()

            val enerji = Math.round((((ls * pco) + (lsl * b)) / 100).toDouble())

            val postMap = hashMapOf<String,Any>()
            postMap.put("Panel Sayisi",binding.panelCount3.text.toString())
            postMap.put("Arazi Eğimi",binding.landSlope.text.toString())
            postMap.put("Arazi Boyutu",binding.panelCount3.text.toString())
            postMap.put("Fatura",binding.bill.text.toString())
            postMap.put("Enerji",enerji.toDouble())
            postMap.put("date",com.google.firebase.Timestamp.now())

            firestore.collection("Enerji").add(postMap).addOnSuccessListener {

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```

These codes are the codes where the calculations of the number that should be written in enerjiText are made and saved in firestore.

```
private fun getData(){
    db.collection("Enerji").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        if (error!=null){
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            if (value !=null){
                if (!value.isEmpty){
                    val documents = value.documents
                    for (document in documents){
                        val panelSayisi = document.get("Panel Sayisi") as String
                        val araziEgimi = document.get("Arazi Eğimi") as String
                        val araziBoyutu = document.get("Arazi Boyutu") as String
                        val faturaDegeri = document.get("Fatura") as String

                        val enerji = Enerji(panelSayisi, araziEgimi, araziBoyutu, faturaDegeri)
                        postArrayList.add(enerji)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("Enerji").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {

                val result : StringBuffer = StringBuffer()
                if (it.isSuccessful){
                    for (document in it.result){
                        result.append(document.data.getValue("Enerji"))
                    }
                    enerjiText.setText(result)
                }
            }
    }
```

These are the codes that I get the data I saved in firebase above and wrote into EnerjiText.

```
data class Enerji (val panelSayisi : String, val araziEgimi : String, val araziBoyutu : String, val faturaDegeri : String)
```

Finally, the Enerji class defined inside the postArrayList, which I think might be the source of the error.

Comment: What exactly in this entire code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: It doesn't check the if-else loop in the first code. As can be seen in the image, the energy is 227. However, although it does not fulfill the (energy<50) condition in the if control in the first code, the progress bars below it show. The progress bars that should show here are the ones under else control. Because the energy value is greater than 50.